# Encrypting a database in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am working with a database I am trying to make secure. I have been able to create the database and access the information within it. However once I try to encrypt the individual pieces of information within the database I run into trouble. I am using sqlite3  for my database and openssl to try to encrypt the database.

```
   local users = [[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username, password);]]
   db:exec( users )

   local nameData = cipher:encrypt ( nameField.text, "sbs_math_key" )
   local passData = cipher:encrypt ( passwordField.text, "sbs_math_key" )

   local tablefill =[[INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, ']].. nameData ..[[',']].. passData ..[['); ]]
   db:exec( tablefill )
```

This works if I am inserting into an existing database, however if I am creating a new database it won't let me insert the encrypted information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        local nameData = mime.b64 ( cipher:encrypt ( nameField.text, "sbs_math_key") )
        local passData = mime.b64 ( cipher:encrypt ( passwordField.text, "sbs_math_key") )

        print( "Before : "..nameData )

        local tablefill =[[INSERT INTO users VALUES (NULL, ']].. nameData ..[[',']].. passData ..[['); ]]
        db:exec( tablefill )

        message = cipher:decrypt ( mime.unb64 ( nameData ), "sbs_math_key" )

        print( "After : "..message )
```